# Sequence id is not properly inserted

Tags: sql, oracle, database-sequence

I have created a sequence but its not inserting ids in sequence order.

For Ex:

- First I have created one set of record seq number generated as 1, 2, 3, 4
- Again I have created another set of records seq started from 8, 9, 10
- For 3rd time I have created another set of records seq id got generated as 5, 6, 7
  (which is not correct, I want the seq id to be continued as 11, 12, 13)

So 5, 6, 7 is wrong, I need 11, 12, 13 to be generated

What's wrong in my below sequence create query?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "LEASE_REPAYMENT_SEQ" 
MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 146724 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE NOKEEP NOSCALE GLOBAL ;
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your sequence, but if you bypass it during INSERT then obviously it will not be incremented

Comment: Are you working on `RAC` with two different sessions? Are yous numbers only *examples* of a wrong order?

Answer (score 3):

If you check the sequence definition, you'll see that you define it as `NOORDER`.

The [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-E9C78A8C-615A-4757-B2A8-5E6EFB130571) says

> Specify NOORDER if you do not want to guarantee sequence numbers are generated in order of request. This is the default.

So what you see is an expected bahaviour and I assume your database is a `RAC` instance (as this effect can be observed on `RAC` only).

Having said that, there are good reasons to allow this small *dis-order* of the assigned `ID`s (which is caused by the *caching* as each `RAC` instance gets it own *cache size* to work with).

The *positive* side of this apprach is that there is  no need to synchronize the sequence between the instances - a task that could produce a big overhead.